# "rs, ri, s, e, h and fs" Query String Parameters from Nginx server

Tags: nginx, video-streaming

I find a lot of video streaming websites that serve FLV or MP4 videos use Nginx web servers.

There are additional parameters such as "rs, ri, s, e, h and fs" with the video file.

For example:

http://www.WEBSITE.com/a%2Fb%2Fabf4f3cd3215e21a7a6d628fb9e15e051371789406-p5762836-p5762842-852-480-1800-h264.flv?**rs**=300&**ri**=600&**s**=1373494458&**e**=1373667258&**h**=87a9298ae0cac65ab1caca51c6dbcfdd&**fs**=0

I am curious what are these parameters and what are they for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The h parameter stands for hash.

Answer (score 0):

`s` and `e` stand for start and end times, you can tell because the parameter value is epoch seconds where `s < e`.

Given that in several websites I've seen this has no relation to the video length, it might be some sort of lease to watch the video? This is just conjecture though.